# How to make Spring Data JPA repository return an exception on no result?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm migrating an existing project to Spring Data JPA repositories.

In the old project my DAOs looks like this:

```
public class MovieDAOImp implements MovieDAO {

    public Movie findByTitle(String title) throws NoResultException {
       /... query the db, if no Movie, throw new NoResultException */
    }

}
```

The new Spring JPA implementation looks like this ...

```
public interface MovieRepository extends JpaRepository<Movie, Integer> {

    Movie findByTitle(String title);

}
```

In the new version `findByTitle` will return null if there's no Movie, but I want it to throw an Exception (preferably my NoResultException, but any exception will do).

The problem I have is all of my Services are implemented expecting the NoResultException to occur.

I don't want to re-work all of my Services to check for nulls.

Is there a way to get the JpaRepository to throw an exception when there is no result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a direct answer to my question, so I came up with this workaround ...

I continue to implement my own DAO and use the `repo` internally.

This has the advantage of giving me complete control over DAO interface, including the exceptions that get thrown, so I don't have to re-work my services.

But it has the disadvantage of adding an extra layer.

```
public class MovieDAOImp implements MovieDAO {

    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository repo;

    public Movie findByTitle(String title) throws NoResultException {
        Movie ret = repo.findByTitle(title);
        if (ret == null) {
            throw new NoResultException("Unable to find movie by title '"+title+"'.");
        }
        return ret;    
    }

}
```

If anyone comes up with a better way to do this, please post an answer!